# two-way sync between mac and unix

Tags: rsync, unison

I would like to work on a directory on two different macs and have access to a unix server that I ssh into. I would like to just start a script at the end of the day that let's me upload all my new/altered files to the server, go home and continue working on my laptop, then sync again to server for the next day.

Google tells me rsync is not the best tool for two-way sync. Most solutions on here suggest unison, but I have been completely unable to get it to work. It gets stuck on "continuing" but shows no signs of actually syncing any files or complains of a fatal error. I even made sure that I run identical versions of unison on both my mac and the server (2.27 & 2.32). No use. I run Mac OSX Snow leopard (laptop) and Mountain Lion (Desktop). What can you recommend? 
Thank you.

Comment: could you give us some more information? are you using the command-line interface? are you able to make a secure-shell connection? are you trying to replicate a large amount of data? the first time unison runs, it needs to fingerprint the files in the directory to sync, which may take some time.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `unsion` for this.

I guess your problem getting to works is related to `ssh`. Make sure unsion is install on both machines and both executables can be accessed *from the local computer you initiated the sync from*. A first test is to issue on the local machine:

```
ssh hostname-of-remote-machine unison -version
```

For more details to make sure SSH access works see in the [unison manual](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html) the section [Remote Shell method](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#rshmeth).

Answer (score 0):

You say that you are using identical versions of Unison on your mac and the server, but then you list the notably different version numbers 2.27 and 2.32. This is the source of your "Fatal Error". Even slightly different versions of Unison use a different format for the archive file that keeps track of the file-system structure.

You need to have *EXACTLY* the same version of Unison on both your machines and the server or else your setup will not work. This is because the format of the archive file that Unison uses to store data about a sync-setup is <s>altered</s> improved almost every small update. Also you should be wary that if you are compiling Unison from source, it *may be* important that each Unison binary is compiled with the same version of OCaml.